# How to get highcharts to display custom marker while maintaining an x time value in data[]

Tags: highcharts

I have highcharts displaying a custom marker based on y value, and I have highcharts displaying x,y values with a given tickerinval. When I put the two together, highcharts chokes on parsing the marker value, I believe it assumes the y value is a date also, but not sure.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/indefire/WQmqN/
Specifically when I change line 50 of the fiddle 
`diastolics.push([dateUTC,this.diastolic]);`
to 
    `diastolics.push([dateUTC,evaluateDiastolic(this.diastolic)];`

but it works fine in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/indefire/VhQMn/2/ where time is not equidistant and the x values are just dates added via

`xAxis: {
categories: readingDates,
type: 'datetime',`

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use categories or datetime, not both. In case when you would like to customise marker for points you can use point object. Instead of `[dateUTC,this.diastolic]` you can use

```
{
   x: dateUTC,
   y: diastolic,
   marker: {
      symbol:'triangle'
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Sebastian! I dont know why i didnt see that sooner, was exactly what I was looking for!! Much Appreciated! Updated Fiddle in case anyone ever needs something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/indefire/WQmqN/6/

Comment: Maybe I'm just obtuse but I think highcharts should update their documentation. When you look at [link]http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.point they only have events as a subtopic.